# How to apply reverb filter or any other sound effect to a .wav sound file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, avfoundation

I need to apply the reverb filter to my sound file in my ipad app.
I just found a keyword AVMetadataID3MetadataKeyReverb in the apple documentation, but not able to get how to use it.
This has been added from iOS 4.0.

Comment: Could you clarify the question a bit? If I understand correctly you are playing a sound file within your app and you would like to programmatically add reverb to it. Does it have to be done dynamically?

Comment: I am recording a sound file in my app. Then I have to provide an option to apply the reverb filter to it.So, I have to achieve this programatically.

Comment: hey man, if the answer helped you would you mind checking it as an answer ? :)

Comment: @Zaky Accepted for a very clear explanation of AVMetadataID3MetadataKeyReverb. :) .. As for sound effects..I am working on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AVMetadataID3MetadataKeyReverb constant represents the RVRB field of and ID3(V2) tag - which is simply a piece of metadata that's part of an audio container file (like MP3). 
The constant isn't related to applying an actual reverb effect to a piece of audio data, but to identifying different parts of ID3 tags when using the AV Foundation to retreive them from an audio file... Later when a supporting audio player plays those files it reads the tags and applies different filters (like the Reverb one) in real time while playing the file.

If you want to modify this value, you'll have to use some external library as Audio Toolbox only knows how to read ID3 tags not writing them. Check out [TagLib](http://developer.kde.org/~wheeler/taglib.html)

If you want to apply effects to some audio data check out [BASS](http://www.un4seen.com/), they have an iPhone library, and many effects including reverb. There might be alternatives though.

Comment: Thanks for your great explanation. I'll check for BASS.

Comment: Hi Zaky, I downloaded the BASS libraries for iPhone from the link www.un4seen.com/stuff/bass24-iphone.zip . But there are only library files i.e. *.a files. I am not able to find any documentation for the libraries and methods to be used. Please help.

Comment: @Ambidextrous http://www.un4seen.com/download.php?bass24-osx get the macOS library here. it comes with documentation, and it's not different from the iPhone calls