# Reverb effect in iPhone app

Tags: ios, audio, soundeffect

Can anyone please give pointers how we can add re verb effect to a recording in an iPhone app?

Vocal live free on app store is a pretty good example of how I would want to include reverb effect.

Core Audio Overview in iOS documentation references reverb as an audio unit.

Any help beyond this will be helpful.

Comment: Did you look into [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750032/how-to-develop-an-iphone-app-with-reverb-functionality) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813746/how-to-apply-reverb-filter-or-any-other-sound-effect-to-a-wav-sound-file). It also mentions Igor's **ObjectAL** answer.

Answer (score 4):

Yoy can use ObjectAL library. See link below
https://github.com/kstenerud/ObjectAL-for-iPhone.

Answer (score -2):

If you have access to the raw audio data, you can simply convolute it with corresponding reverberation finite impulse response (FIR) filter kernel.

Comment: Doesn't sound very simple without additional explanation.

Comment: @Remover Google for FIR and convolution. What do you expect, that I write a code in your place?